How to install cmake in wsl on windows?
I have WSL running on my Windows computer and when I install it  cmake it accessible only in command prompt not WSL. How can I get access to it from my Powershell WSL Window?

You need to install cmake within WSL, rather than within Windows. Fire up your WSL distro and install the cmake package from your distribution's repo. For example, on Debian-based distros:
sudo apt install cmake
This will install the CMake tools for linux, within WSL.
